# Why some seeds are mucilaginous (chia, rucola)?

Tags: evolution

Why some seeds are mucilaginous (chia, rucola)? 
It is not obvious what kind of preferences that can bring to them. What is a role of mucilage in seeds cultivation?

P.S. The cultivation in germination cup shows only "difficulties": more affected by micro-flora, harder consequences after become too dry...